# Are webkit transitions slower after iOS 5 upgrade?

Tags: uiwebview, webkit, ios5

I'm experiencing slower webkit animations in UIWebView embedded apps after upgrading my iPad 2 to iOS 5. Two of my apps are noticeably jerky during multiple animations and transforms.

The simplest animation I have that demonstrates this is doing three things: scrolling a 2048x768 image to the left, moving a smaller image to the right and scaling it down, and playing an audio clip via AVAudioPlayer.

It's all jerky after the upgrade, even when I'm not running anything else. Memory isn't leaking or increasing in size. I did a CPU profile on the app before the upgrade, no problems there.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an intermittent problem - the app looks fine this morning. I suspect there's network operations occurring on the app. I have another I'm working on that has lots of transitions but doesn't require network access, so I might see if I can duplicate the problem over there.

For now, I'll just live with it and watch for it to reoccur.